Can doubly parabolic Blaschke product (BP) contained in another doubly parabolic BP?
Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ be a degree $d$ doubly parabolic Blaschke product with Denjoy-Wolff point at $z=1$. That is, $f(1) = 1$, $f'(1)=1$ and $f''(1)=0$.
Let $U \subset \mathbb{D}$ be simply connected so $f^{-1}(U)=U$ invariant and contain all critical points of $f$. I have a proof of existence for such $U$ but it's not relevant here.
We can take Riemann map $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$, and consider the conjugation $g= \varphi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. Then $g$ is also a degree $d$ parabolic Blaschke product.
Question: Assuming $U \subsetneq \mathbb{D}$ proper subset, can $g$ be a doubly parabolic Blaschke product?
Attempt: I think no. Assume $g$ be doubly parabolic. Let $P \subset \mathbb{D}$ be a maximal petal of $g$. In particular $\bigcup_n g^{-n}(P) = \mathbb{D}$.
(this is the sketchy part) Let $\tilde{P} = \varphi^{-1}(P)$. I want to say $\tilde{P}$ is also a maximal petal of $f$.
Assuming so, since $\tilde{P} \subset U$ which is invariant, we know $f^{-n}(\tilde{P}) \subset U$ and by the property of petal, again $\bigcup_n f^{-n}(\tilde{P}) = \mathbb{D}$. Consequently $U = \mathbb{D}$, contradiction.

If $U\subset D$ is connected and $f^{-1}(U)=U$, then necessarily $U=D$. So I am afraid that your proof that such $U\neq D$ exists cannot be correct.

I thought similarly until last week my advisor pointed out: Recall the quotient $\mathbb{D}/$ is infinite cylinder with critical points marked. Define $U$ to be this cylinder minus the two ends, keeping all critical points inside $U$.
Also, at some point I should visit Purdue to meet you :) (I'm based in Bloomington). Learned a lot from your contribution to stack exchange.

sorry, I did not understand your construction. You are certainly welcome to visit Purdue, but please take into account that I am retiring since 2025, and after that it will be harder to find me here:-)

For your (advisor's) construction, the quotient $\mathbb{D}/\langle g\rangle$ must be isomorphic to an annulus of finite modulus. So the corresponding fixed point is attracting and cannot be parabolic.

@inyo oops you are correct, the correct construction is the Ecale cylinder minus only one ends. Thanks for pointing out.

Since $f$ doubly parabolic, then $P$ maximal petal of $f$ is entirely contained in $\mathbb{D}$. Since $\bigcup_n f^{-n}(P) = \mathbb{D}$ by definition of petal, we have $\mathbb{D}/ \langle f \rangle := \left\{ [z]  \,\,| \,\, z\in \mathbb{D}  \text{ and } [z]=[f(z)] \right\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ punctured plane (equivalently infinite cylinder, often referred as Ecalle cylinder). Similarly then $\mathbb{D} / \langle g \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$. Observe the conformaly conjugacy map $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ give conformal isomorphism $U / \langle f \rangle \cong \mathbb{D} / \langle g \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}^*$.
The injection map $U \hookrightarrow \mathbb{D}$ descend to the quotient under dynamics of $f$ giving a conformal injection $U / \langle f \rangle \hookrightarrow \mathbb{D} / \langle f \rangle$. However any injective holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ must be either $z \mapsto c z$ or $z \mapsto c/z$ for $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$ by removable singularity theorem. In particular it is surjective, which combined with $f^{-1}(U) = U$ totally invariant imply $U = \mathbb{D}$.

Now since Prof. Eremenko ask for the construction of such U, the idea is to take a sequence of quadratic polynomial $f_\lambda(z)= z^2 + \lambda z$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\lambda \rightarrow 1$ along a horocycle. This sequence will exhibit Julia set that does not converge to the Julia set of $z^2+z$, rather a subset. The picture of the limiting Julia set is the following white/grey region. Observe the grey region is forward invariant and contains critical point (to justify forward invariant one need to show Caratheodory convergence of basin of $z=0$).

Now take the the Riemann map of parabolic basin of $z^2+z$. This conjugate $z^2+z$ to a parabolic Blaschke product, which by local connectivity of the Julia set of $z^2+z$ we know the conjugacy extend to the boundary giving the resulting Blaschke product is doubly parabolic.
$U$ is defined to be the image of the grey region under the Riemann map.
